# Get tinyMCE content in raw/text format without using active editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to have the raw/text format from an tinyMCE editor.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'})
```

will do the job, but I have 2 editors in the same page (with different ids of course).

I need to count characters on window.onload, but at this moment i have no editor focused.

```
tinyMCE.get('my_editor').getContent()
```

can do the job but it doesn't take any parameters to format the output, it only returns html.

How can I get the raw content of a tinyMCE editor by id?

Comment: What happens if you do try `tinyMCE.get('my_editor').getContent({format: 'raw'})`? Still does html?

Answer (score 1):

There are likely two issues at play here...

TinyMCE is likely not fully initialized when the window's `onload` event fires. 
 Trying to use TinyMCE APIs before the editor is initialized simply won't work.  Here is a TinyMCE fiddle that shows how to fire code as soon as the editor is loaded using TinyMCE's `init` callback:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5pgaab/2

If you fire code at the correct time, TinyMCE's `get()` API uses the ID of the textarea to identify a specific editor instance.  What is even easier is the `init` callback in the demo fiddle automatically gets access to the editor instance via a variable TinyMCE passes in to the function so that editor instance can be used to call `getContent()` without the need to first locate the editor.

**EDIT:** If you just want the text characters (no HTML tags) you can use a different format parameter in the getContent() call:

```
editor.getContent({format: 'text'})
```

Here is an updated example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5pgaab/3

Comment: Even in raw, it still have html. the main purpose (maybe i was not clear) was to count the caracters typed.

Comment: Then just use a different version of the getContent() call:  `editor.getContent({format: 'text'})`

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5pgaab/3